# After creating catkin workspace for ros noetic i received the following message

Tags: ros

```
bash: /home/mohammad/catkim_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the instructions and likely you'll see the problem.

Comment: A single line in an unreadable picture. Do not show pictures of text include the text in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `bash: /home/mohammad/catkim_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory` error message was probably caused by a typo error. catkin is the official build system of ROS. Try it with catkin_ws instead of catkim_ws.